# Need same method for iOS 7

Tags: swift, ios7

I am developing an iOS application and I want all phones with iOS 7 and up to be able to use the application. When I set it to iOS 7 three methods cannot be used as they are only available on iOS 8 and newer. Does anyone know the older methods. here is the code with the error...

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.init(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil) //Error: UIserNotificationSettings is only available on iOS 8 and newer 
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings) //Error:  registerUserNotificationSettings is only available on iOS 8 and newer 

application.registerForRemoteNotifications() //Error: registerForRemoteNotifications is only available on iOS 8 and newer
```

Comment: This may guide you http://corinnekrych.blogspot.mx/2014/07/how-to-support-push-notification-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using swift 2.0, the new correct way for checking the OS version is this:

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    // do iOS 9 stuff here
} else {
    // do pre iOS 9 stuff here
}
```

So in your particular case you'll want something like this.

```
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.init(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
} else {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Sound, .Alert, .Badge])
}
```

Furthermore if your minimum deployment target is more than what you're checking (deploy for 9, but checking against 8) the compiler will warn you of the check being redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to get it working from http://corinnekrych.blogspot.com.au/2014/07/how-to-support-push-notification-for.html, and converted it into Swift:

```
if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.init(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
} else {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Sound, .Alert, .Badge])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the methods are still not available on iOS 7

Comment: In case you didn't figure it out, the code checks if the iOS 8+ method exists. If it does, run the needed code, otherwise run the older code. `- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` is marked deprecated for iOS 8+.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check to see if this is an iOS 8 device.
let iOS8 = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
if iOS8 {
    // Register for push in iOS 8
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
} else {        
    // Register for push in iOS 7
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert)
}
```

Does this work for you?